# Removing parts of a string in quotation marks from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-lab

I wrote a .csv to a Pandas DataFrame and some of the column values need to be stripped.
As an example, the `state` needs to have ''region:'' removed, however any code I try inc `replace()` or `lstrip()` doesn't seem to work. I think this is because the string values I want to remove, themselves, contain single quotation marks.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

E.G 'region':'CA' should be 'CA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To clean the cells, [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) on `': '`, with `expand=True`. Take element `[1]`, and then [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) the extra `'` from around the strings.
- It looks like `': '` to me, but if there's no space, then split on `':'`
- For `.replace`, try `.replace("'", '')` or `.replace('"', '')`

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample
restaurant_df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ["'region': 'CA'"], 'latitude': ["'latitude': 37.787086"], 'longitude': ["'longitude': -122.400212"],
                              'tel': ["'tel': '(415) 512-8113'"], 'price': ["'price': '1'"], 'rating': ["'rating': 3.0"]})


# display
            state               latitude                 longitude                      tel         price         rating
0  'region': 'CA'  'latitude': 37.787086  'longitude': -122.400212  'tel': '(415) 512-8113'  'price': '1'  'rating': 3.0

# fix all the columns with "'...: ...'"
cols = ['state', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'tel', 'price', 'rating']

for col in cols:
    restaurant_df[col] = restaurant_df[col].str.split(': ', expand=True)[1].str.replace("'", '')

# display repaired dataframe
  state   latitude    longitude             tel price rating
0    CA  37.787086  -122.400212  (415) 512-8113     1    3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```py
restaurant_df['state'] = restaurant_df['state'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: try this]

You can also try this:

```
restaurant_df.state=restaurant_df.state.str.replace("'region':",'')
```

Answer (score 0):

restaurant_df['state'] = restaurant_df['state'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip("'region':"))